# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener function not being called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to make an extension that if you put a twitter username in the address bar and press enter, it will go to that twitter page instead of going to google, but it doesn't even trigger the function no matter what I enter in the address bar.

Manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Twitter link",
  "description": "Type in a username with @ preceding it to go to that twitter page, ex: @wol_lay would go to https://twitter.com/wol_lay",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*.google.com"
  ],
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]}
}
```

My code

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details)
  {
    console.log (details.url);
    if (details.url.charAt (0) == '@')
    {
      return {redirectUrl: "https://www.twitter.com/" + details.url.substring(1,details.url.length - 1)};
    }
  },

  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},

  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: Chrome never sends an HTTP request for `@whatever` (because that's not a valid hostname or URL), so there's no HTTP request to intercept. Chrome probably *will* send a request to the user's search provider (Google, Yahoo, or whatever it's set to) with `@whatever` somewhere in the query string, though. In that case, however, it might be difficult to distinguish between a genuine search attempt and an entry from the omnibox.

Comment: You say it "doesn't trigger the function no matter what I enter", but you should see the result from the `console.log(details.url)` at least. Are you looking at your background page's console, from the link in `chrome://extensions`?

Comment: My advice? Use [chrome.omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html) with the keyword "@". Then all someone would have to do is type `@ [space/tab] whatever` in the address bar for the username to be sent to your background page. (Listen for it with `chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered`.)

Comment: I was getting nothing in the console when doing normal links.